# Message not showing after it exceeds over the amount limit

Tags: java

The message is not showing when I enter a number over 3999

I tried to move the message inside the method but that just causes more errors.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class RomanNumerals {

    public static String convert(int n) {
String roman = "";
if ((n >= 0) && (n <= 3999)) {
    int thousand = (n / 1000);
    int hundred = (n % 1000) / 100;
    int tens = (n % 100) / 10;
    int units = (n % 10);

    if (thousand >= 1) {
        if (thousand == 1)
            roman += "M";
        else if (thousand == 2)
            roman += "MM";
        else roman += "MMM";
    }

    if (hundred >= 0) {
        if (hundred == 0)
            roman += "";
        else if (hundred == 1)
            roman += "C";
        else if (hundred == 2)
            roman += "CC";
        else if (hundred == 3)
            roman += "CCC";
        else if (hundred == 4)
            roman += "CD";
        else if (hundred == 5)
            roman += "D";
        else if (hundred == 6)
            roman += "DC";
        else if (hundred == 7)
            roman += "DCC";
        else if (hundred == 8)
            roman += "DCCC";
        else
            roman += "CM";
    }

    if (tens >= 0) {
        if (tens == 0)
            roman += "";
        else if (tens == 1)
            roman += "X";
        else if (tens == 2)
            roman += "XX";
        else if (tens == 3)
            roman += "XXX";
        else if (tens == 4)
            roman += "XL";
        else if (tens == 5)
            roman += "L";
        else if (tens == 6)
            roman += "LX";
        else if (tens == 7)
            roman += "LXX";
        else if (tens == 8)
            roman += "LXXX";
        else
            roman += "XC";
    }

    if (units >= 0) {
        if (units == 0)
            roman += "";
        else if (units == 1)
            roman += "I";
        else if (units == 2)
            roman += "II";
        else if (units == 3)
            roman += "III";
        else if (units == 4)
            roman += "IV";
        else if (units == 5)
            roman += "V";
        else if (units == 6)
            roman += "VI";
        else if (units == 7)
            roman += "VII";
        else if (units == 8)
            roman += "VIII";
        else
            roman += "IX";
    }
} else {
    roman = "Number cannot be converted as it exceeds over 3999";
}
return roman;
```

}

I expect the output after the user enters over 3999 to show the message "Number cannot be converted as it exceeds over 3999" but when I write a number over 3999 the program just stops. Everything else worked fine and shows the correct integers in roman numerals

Can someone help me with this because I am very confused

Comment: Please indent your code properly so it's legible.

Comment: indentation is for Human benefit.  It is there to enable Humans to clearly understand  the code which enables coding errors to be found.

Comment: At the moment it looks like the `else` clause is linked to the `if (units >= 0)` clause

Comment: And just another note, don't omit `{}`s. Not adding them only saves a few keystrokes, but allows for a whole range of errors. Except for very limited cases, `{}` should always be used.

Comment: And still.... no decent indentation of the code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Classic case of how you can miss seeing the problem because of poor indentation.

The following `else` is with the `if (units >= 0)` instead of being with `if ((n >= 0) && (n <= 3999))`:

```
} else {
    roman = "Number cannot be converted as it exceeds over 3999";
}
```

Also, on an unrelated note, your condition in `if (units >= 0)` is always true, so you might want to remove this check or change it.

**Edit**: full `convert` method after fixing the closing brace:

```
public static String convert(int n) {
    String roman = "";
    if ((n >= 0) && (n <= 3999)) {
        int thousand = (n / 1000);
        int hundred = (n % 1000) / 100;
        int tens = (n % 100) / 10;
        int units = (n % 10);

        if (thousand >= 1) {
            if (thousand == 1)
                roman += "M";
            else if (thousand == 2)
                roman += "MM";
            else roman += "MMM";
        }

        if (hundred >= 0) {
            if (hundred == 0)
                roman += "";
            else if (hundred == 1)
                roman += "C";
            else if (hundred == 2)
                roman += "CC";
            else if (hundred == 3)
                roman += "CCC";
            else if (hundred == 4)
                roman += "CD";
            else if (hundred == 5)
                roman += "D";
            else if (hundred == 6)
                roman += "DC";
            else if (hundred == 7)
                roman += "DCC";
            else if (hundred == 8)
                roman += "DCCC";
            else
                roman += "CM";
        }

        if (tens >= 0) {
            if (tens == 0)
                roman += "";
            else if (tens == 1)
                roman += "X";
            else if (tens == 2)
                roman += "XX";
            else if (tens == 3)
                roman += "XXX";
            else if (tens == 4)
                roman += "XL";
            else if (tens == 5)
                roman += "L";
            else if (tens == 6)
                roman += "LX";
            else if (tens == 7)
                roman += "LXX";
            else if (tens == 8)
                roman += "LXXX";
            else
                roman += "XC";
        }

        if (units >= 0) {
            if (units == 0)
                roman += "";
            else if (units == 1)
                roman += "I";
            else if (units == 2)
                roman += "II";
            else if (units == 3)
                roman += "III";
            else if (units == 4)
                roman += "IV";
            else if (units == 5)
                roman += "V";
            else if (units == 6)
                roman += "VI";
            else if (units == 7)
                roman += "VII";
            else if (units == 8)
                roman += "VIII";
            else
                roman += "IX";
        }
    } else {
        roman = "Number cannot be converted as it exceeds over 3999";
    }
    return roman;
}
```

Comment: @Ray I have added the corrected method to the answer. You should (must!) use an IDE like IntelliJ or Eclipse, which will indent your code.